testing the index.js file react Target container is not a DOM element
I tried writing a test for this file but received the error Target container is not a DOM element. All the needed files were imported.
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
//other files imported

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(
    <AppRoot>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <title className='myAppTitle' id="myApp">MY APP</title>
          <div data-testId="index">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/*" element={ <App /> } />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </AppRoot>
    ,
    rootElement,
);

This is the jest test I tried. I expected the test to pass. I imported all the needed imports but the test is failing at .render(). The error says Target container is not a DOM element. Is there a way to get test coverage for an index.js file of a react app?
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
//other files imported

describe('index', () => {
    jest.mock('react-dom', ()=> ({render: jest.fn()}))
    const root = document.createElement('div');

    beforeEach(() => {
        document.body.appendChild(root);
    })
    it('should render without crashing', async () => {
       const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(
    <AppRoot>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <title className='myapptitle' id="myapp">MY APP</title>
          <div data-testId="index">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/*" element={ <App /> } />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </AppRoot>
    ,
    rootElement,
);
 expect(title).toBe('My App');
 expect(document.getElementById('myApp')).toBeTruthy();
    });
})


You have created the root element but forgot to assign an ID to to thats why

document.getElementById(“root”)

Returns null and no target container is found.
Easier way out is just write
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root') || document.createElement(“div”);

So it would create a rootElement if not found.
Or you could assign an id to rootElement using
rootElement.setAttribute('id', 'root');

One suggestion from my side. Prefer writing tests using actual file imports rather than making a copy of the file code.
Also mock should be something like this:
jest.mock('react-dom/client', () => ({
  createRoot: jest.fn().mockImplementation((element) =>         {
    return {
      render: jest.fn(),
    };
  }),
}));

With test to be something like
expect(root.render).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Your whole test doesn't seem right. Please explore a bit more on jest.
